# Direx not working, cl-call-next-method only inside primary and around methods

Tags: common-lisp

### Setup:

GUI version GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
of 2015-07-25 on KAEL

[Compiled from EmacsW64.](http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/)

Direx, using the latest version of Direx from MELPA

Windows 7 x64 bit.

### Situation:

I would like to try the package [Direx](https://github.com/m2ym/direx-el), but the documentation is not very clear.When I installed Direx, I try to start it wih <kbd>M-x Direx:jump-to-directory</kbd> but I get a unclear message:

```
cl-call-next-method: cl-call-next-method only allowed inside primary and around methods
```

When googling around, I found this [thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2015-06/msg00473.html) but it's difficult to understand how this error occured in a package. It's more related with common Lisp than the package itself, it seems.

When I tried again with the empty Emacs configuration (`emacs -q`), I still  get the same message. It's unclear to me what I do need to solve this error, in order to get Direx working.

Direx is downloaded more than 10.000 times ,but I don't know how I could call Direx. The commands for Direx seems obfuscated to me. Seems I am the only one with this bug?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, consider contacting the package author. (A priori, this sounds like a bug.)

Comment: It' s a bug in direx.el where the code calls `cl-call-next-method` inside an EIEIO method (they should either switch to a cl-generic method, or use EIEIO's `call-next-method`).

Comment: You're getting the same bug? Direx is downloaded more than  10.000 times ,but I cannot activate Direx. Seems im the only one with this bug?

Comment: It's a recent regression (for which I am responsible). I have opened a new pull request with the fix: https://github.com/m2ym/direx-el/pull/48. (I switched to `cl-call-next-method` in the wrong commit "switch to cl-lib" instead of in "use cl-defmethod, not for immediate merging".)

Comment: Once that has been merged, you should probably delete this question, because I am not going to provide an answer to claim the extra 50 - that wouldn't seem right.

Comment: @tarsius, after 2 days of waiting and upgrading, Direx is working again! Thanks for your fix and reply, it's appreciated!

Comment: @ReneFroger yes, Melpa has occasionally been taking a long time lately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a bug in Direx which was fixed by @tarsius, my thanks to him. So I consider this issue as being closed.